# Assigning a variable from a different file with a string

Tags: python

In the file values there are a bunch of lists and I want to assign gun_type to a value depending on what my current_gun_name is plus the string _Iron.

How do I do this? This is my current code but it doesnt work

```py
current_gun_name = string_assigned_above
    iron = win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x67)
    if iron < KeyMin and win32api.GetAsyncKeyState(0x11) < 0:
        gun_type = values.(current_gun_name + "_Iron")
```

So, on the last line there I am trying to pull a list from another file called values. But the list that I am trying to pull depends on the current_gun_name string. For example:

```py
current_string = "test" 
list_from_values = values.(current_gun_name + "ing") 
print(list_from_values)
```

In this code it should find a list in the file called values. The list it will find and print will be called "testing" as I am asking it to use the variable plus "ing" Except this doesnt work

Comment: could you be a little clear on what you want to do?

Comment: So, on the last line there I am trying to pull a list from another file called values. But the list that I am trying to pull depends on the current_gun_name string. For example:

Comment: ````
current_string = "test"
list_from_values = values.(current_gun_name + "ing")
print(list_from_values)
```

In this code it should find a list in the file called values. The list it will find and print will be called "testing" as I am asking it to use the variable plus "ing"

Except this doesnt work @SadafShafi

Comment: Please [edit] your answer with the clarifications.

Comment: Done @joseville